# SparkAR - how to track a plane surface (not image target)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, tracking, spark-ar-studio

Is there any way to implement target tracking in SparkAR, but track the current plane where the 3d object is placed, instead of a predefined target image?

So, for example, I'm placing a 3D object on a paper with a drawing, and when I move the paper around, the object should stick to it. But it can be any drawing, not some predefined target image. It already works like this with a plane tracker, the only problem is that it works if I move, but not if the plane itself moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, there is a MOVING_OBJECT option inside the tracking mode ENUM (https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/enums/scenemodule.trackingmode/) that could be what you're looking for? You can access the enum through the scene module, I think, and then declare that the tracking mode you want for X object on the scene is this one (you can find some good tutorials on yt, but this https://github.com/jordyhenry/PlaneTracker.trackingMode might be a good start). 
 But bear in mind that vertical_plane, for example, simply does not work anymore. So you'd have to try and see if the moving_object one is still a thing – fb does not seem worried about retrocompatibility so they just... stop using things on updates.

Comment: Thank you, will look into that

Answer (score 1):

As per the current version (102)
Target tracking is fixed such that, (using your example) it should be a specific drawing and once that paper with the drawing is detected, the 3D object will show, and when the drawing is moved, the 3D object will remain at the same place

It works with the plane tracker, as for the plane tracker, the user decides where to place the object but as for target tracking, it's a fixed position